# How to pass hidden form field using post method in jsp to servlet filter's doFilter method?

Tags: jsp, servlets

jsp code:

```
<form name="editAddress" id="editAddress"  method ="post" >
<td ><input type="hidden" name="csrf" id="csrf" value="<%=token%>"></input>
```

Servlet Filter:

```
public class ValidateToken implements Filter  
    {
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException 
        {
           HttpServletRequest httpRequest = request instanceof HttpServletRequest ? (HttpServletRequest) request : null;
           HttpServletResponse httpResponse = response instanceof HttpServletResponse ? (HttpServletResponse) response: null;

            String token =httpRequest.getParameter("csrf");

            System.out.println("token =" +token);

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Here the token value is null in ValidateToken class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **method parameter** `request`, not some self-defined field.

(I don't even see where these fields `request` and `response` in line 3 and 4 even come from. `Filter` is an Interface, and, as such, has no fields. Is this even compilable?)

Remove the two fields, and cast the method parameter `request` to `HttpServletRequest`, and it will work.

Comment: Hi gsl, There was slight correction in the code, Please find the updated code. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Are you sure that posting the form will be processed by this filter? I see no `action` attribute in the `<form>` tag.  Maybe you see "token=null" for all other `GET` requests, and not for the 'POST` coming from your JSP? Maybe add the complete `<form>` element (closing tag is missing here too) and the Filter's mapping.